# Chat application using Pubnub

Tags: android, chat, publish-subscribe, pubnub

I am developing chat application using `Pubnub`.
I have successfully created group chat using `Publish/subscribe`.

Now I want to develop one-one chat using `Pubnub`. I am trying using `PnGcmMessage` but chat not working.

If anyone knows this, please help me !!

Comment: Nancy - If you managed to get group chat working then all you need to do is prevent more than two people from joining the channel and you have private chat. But I know what you are really asking is how to get two people to *start* chatting. How does one user invite another user to a private chat, correct?

Comment: See this for some insights using JavaScript. Different code, same concept: https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-09-02-javascript-private-chat-api-with-access-control/   and this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843909/pubnub-publish-message-between-two-private-channels

Comment: Exactly I want one user to invite second user for private chat.

Comment: I got the solution from Github https://github.com/WizTheEngineer/DroidMessenger but using Parse .

Comment: Er.Nancy Thakkar - thanks for finding and providing. Tossed all helpful links  in official answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have successfully created one-one chat using Pubnub.Here is the useful links

- https://github.com/WizTheEngineer/DroidMessenger
- [Android chat application guidance using Parse and PubNub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21127654/android-chat-application-)  guidance-using-parse-and-pubnub
  -https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android-java/api-reference

Answer (score 1):

Providing all helpful links here as the answer:

- [DroidMessenger - Github Repo](https://github.com/WizTheEngineer/DroidMessenger): sample Android app for PubNub 1-1 chat
- [Private chat example using PubNub JavaScript SDK](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-09-02-javascript-private-chat-api-with-access-control/) and PubNub Access Manager for authorization security
- An older but thorough discussion on [StackOverflow about PubNub private chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843909/pubnub-publish-message-between-two-private-channels)